# StatusBar issue with videojs Fullscreen in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3, video.js

I use a Component to run videos js in an ionic application
I want the application to cover the status bar when click fullscreen in the video
This code works only when i put in  'constructor', put when i put inside the fullscreen handle function it does not work.

```
statusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
```

I explained the code where it works and where i want it to work in this code using comments like this //* FULLSCREEN WORKS THERE * and //* FULLSCREEN Does Not WORK THERE *

```
import {Component,OnInit,OnDestroy,ElementRef,Input} from '@angular/core';
import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'videojs-contrib-hls';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
    selector: 'videojs',
    template: '<video *ngIf="url" id="video_{{idx}}" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered vjs-16-9" controls autoplay preload="auto" [poster]="poster" width="640" height="264"><source [src]="url" type="application/x-mpegURL" /></video>',
})

export class VideoJSComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() idx: string;
    @Input() url: any;
    @Input() poster: any;
    private player: any; 

    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef, platform: Platform, private statusBar: StatusBar) {
        this.url = false;
        this.player = false;
        //statusBar.overlaysWebView(true); //* FULLSCREEN WORKS THERE *
    }
    ngOnInit() { }
    ngOnDestroy() { }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    let el = 'video_' + this.idx;
    this.player = videojs(document.getElementById(el), {"html5": {
        "hls": {
            "withCredentials": true,
        }, 
    },
    "techOrder": ["html5"],
    resolve: {
    alias: {
        'video.js$': 'video.js/dist/video.cjs.js',
        'videojs-contrib-hls': 'videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls',
    },
    }
    }, function() {

    var myPlayer = this, id = myPlayer.id();

    // Handle fullscreen
    myPlayer.on('fullscreenchange',function() {
        if( myPlayer.isFullscreen() == true) {
            console.log(myPlayer.isFullscreen());
            document.body.classList.add("vjsFull");
            //statusBar.overlaysWebView(true); //* FULLSCREEN Does Not WORK THERE *
            //this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(true); //* FULLSCREEN Does Not WORK THERE *
        }else {
            document.body.classList.remove("vjsFull");
        }
    });

    // Make up an aspect ratio
    var aspectRatio = 264/640;

    // internal method to handle a window resize event to adjust the video player
    function resizeVideoJS(){
        var width = document.getElementById(id).parentElement.offsetWidth;
        myPlayer.width(width);
        myPlayer.height( width * aspectRatio );
    }
    resizeVideoJS();
    window.onresize = resizeVideoJS;
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for who face the same issue
define this to another variable before the fullscreen function

```
var _this = this;
```

then use in in the fullscreen function like this

```
_this.statusBar.hide();
```

.

```
export class VideoJSComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  ...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      var _this = this;
      this.player = videojs(document.getElementById(el), {

          ...

      }, function() {
          // Handle fullscreen
          myPlayer.on('fullscreenchange', function() {
              if (myPlayer.isFullscreen() == true) {
                  ...
                  _this.statusBar.hide();
              }
              else {
                  ...
                  _this.statusBar.show();
              }
          });
      });
  }
}
```